# Access form - saving multiple records for the same client

Tags: forms, ms-access

I'm a novice, as you will see.  I have been piecing two Access forms together using an Access for Dummies book, lots of internet searches, and trial-and-error.

I am trying to create two Access forms which interact with each other.  The first is a form that will let counselors log information about counseling appointments while displaying some read-only demographic data about the client.  This demographic data will come from a table that is used by a second form, which is a read-only form that displays demographics about a client who is selected from a combobox and which includes a subform that shows the data from the counseling appointment form -- so a summary of all the info about that client and their previous appts at a glance.

All the clients have an SSO - this is my primary key in my demographics table.  I have a one-to-many relationship set up with a counseling log table based on SSO.  The counseling log table has an autoID as its foreign key because that will be the only unique field.

My read-only demographics form with subform works fine.  My problem is getting the counseling log to save to the counseling log table that is used by that subform.  If I just enter some sample data directly into in the counseling log table datasheet, it's all fine, but I don't understand how to get data from the counseling log form to save to the table.  I want the SSO (from the demographics table) to save along with the counseling log data that gets entered by the user, but I cannot figure out how to do that.  I have tried copying the read-only SSO field that comes from a combobox, using the expression builder to take SSO from the demographics table, just letting the user copy and paste the SSO from the read-only field (an act of desperation)....  I get an error message: You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in the demographics table.  So I'm not relating my counseling log to the SSO properly -- how do I do that in such a way that I can enter multiple counseling logs for the same SSO?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Options are form/subform arrangement or selecting from combobox or code to pass value between forms. Question is really too broad and there is no code for analysis so not really appropriate for SO. Might post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis. Surely you mean the autoID field is a PRIMARY key, not FOREIGN.

Comment: on the Ribbon under Database Tools have you used the relationships tool to tell access about the relationships between the Tables?  While you are learning, I recommend letting Access create an autonumber primary key like DemographicTableID for each client and add SSO as a separate column.  Then add a column called DemographicTableID to CounselingLogs which has its own autonumber primary key called CounselingLogID.  in the relationships tool drag DemographicTableID from either table onto the other to get the arrow.  Access will know that the primary key is the 1 and the foreign key is the many.

Comment: that is drag DemographicTableID from the Demographic Table on to DemographicTableID in the CounselingLogs. or vice versa.